# Why doesn't .simulate("mouseover") work in a Jest / Enzyme test?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, material-ui, dom-events, enzyme

I've a simple example of a material-ui `ListItem` which I mouse over and a material-ui `Popper` containing another `ListItem` then appears on the `onMouseOver` event. This works fine but I can't replicate the behavior in the associated Jest/Enzyme Test.

Cut down example with failing test here.

[image: Edit priceless-bose-6hi04]

**Component Snippet**

```
export default function MyPopoutMenu() {
  const [popoverAnchorElement, setPopoverAnchorElement] = useState(null);
  const handleMouseEnter = event => {
    console.log("onMouseEnter - " + event.currentTarget.textContent);
    setPopoverAnchorElement(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleClose = (event, index) => {
    console.log("closing");
    setPopoverAnchorElement(null);
  };

  let isPopoverOpen = Boolean(popoverAnchorElement);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <List style={{ maxWidth: "250px" }}>
        <ListItem button>
          <ListItemIcon>
            <FolderIcon />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter}>
            Hover on me
          </ListItemText>
        </ListItem>
      </List>
      <Popper
        open={isPopoverOpen}
        onClose={handleClose}
        anchorEl={popoverAnchorElement}
        className="popper-item"
      >
        <ListItem button>
          <ListItemIcon>
            <KeyboardArrowRightIcon />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText>I Appear</ListItemText>
        </ListItem>
      </Popper>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Test Snippet**

```
/** Interaction tests testing user interaction with PilzButton */
test("Check that popover appears on hover", () => {
  const wrapper = mount(<MyPopoutMenu />);
  console.log("wrapper DEBUG - " + wrapper.debug());

  //1. Find the menu item to hover on
  const foundListItem = wrapper
    .find(".MuiListItemText-root")
    .filterWhere(item => item.contains("Hover on me"));
  expect(foundListItem).toHaveLength(1);

  //2. Hover on the item
  foundListItem.prop("onMouseEnter")({
    currentTarget: {
      textContent: "Hover on me"
    }
  });
  act(() => {
    //Now try to find the Popover
    const foundPopoverListItem = wrapper
      .find(".MuiListItemText-root")
      .filterWhere(item => item.contains("I Appear"));

    expect(foundPopoverListItem).toHaveLength(1);
  });
});
```

Comment: What happens when you change it to `foundListItem.simulate("mouseenter");`?

Comment: The same thing happens :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update the wrapper before acting

Tests passing in sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-leaf-7ko8v

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at this discussion about the use of `simulate`:

https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/1606

So in a nutshell the recommendation is **not** to use it at all but to instead do as follows:

```
foundListItem.prop('onMouseEnter')();
```

You can even pass in a mock event to the `handleMouseEnter` function as follows:

```
foundListItem.prop('onMouseEnter')({
  currentTarget: {
    textContent: 'I Appear'
  }
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This works! However when my handler get fired when the ```mouseEnter``` event gets fired the ```event``` object is null. Strange?!   ```onMouseEnter={(event: Event) => ```

Comment: Just be mindful of the syntax of your mock event. Especially if you need something very specific to be handled during that `handleMouseEnter` and `setPopoverAnchorElement` functions. Make sure everything required by both methods is mocked.

Comment: Ah yes I see. I think it probably does but looks like it might need an extra wrapping in an act call. Got the following warning When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):. Should be easy enough to sort hopefully.

Comment: Ah OK right I have seen that. That's because of your use of the `useState` hook in React. You will need to mock those React hooks too (from my experience anyway). I'm not sure of the exact reasons behind it but `jest` doesn't use React hooks out of the box. You'll have to mock those functions instead.

Comment: Still doesn't work with the suggestion above unfortunately. Codebox here with your suggested solution - https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-bose-6hi04   Also updated in original question above.